# Hybris Update Hot-Folder Process

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder

How to add new attribute for CSV file and how/where to update the code of the `hot-folder` process?

Answer (score 5):

In the Hybris `Hot Folder` principle, we convert a `CSV` file to an `ImpEx` file using the specific header that can be configured using Spring Integration logic.

***Files to update/configure:***

To specify/add/update the configuration of your `Hot Folder` logic/header look for a file named something like `hot-folder-spring.xml` in the `hot-folder` custom extension.

***What to add :***

Add your *attribute* in the `ImpEx` header of your type located in `hot-folder` configuration file, something like :

```
<bean id="myTypeConverter" class="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.converter.impl.DefaultImpexConverter">
    <property name="header">
        <value># ImpEx for Importing MyType objects into $CATALOG$
            $catalog=$CATALOG$
            #% impex.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
            INSERT_UPDATE MyType;code[unique=true];myAttribute[translator=com.dataimport.batch.converter.MyAttributeTranslator]// translator if need
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="impexRow">
        <value>;{+0};{+1}</value> //{+1} = the number 1 is the position of the column of your attribute value {+csv-attribute-column-position}
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Note:**

> Hot Folder, is a folder from which data can be automatically imported
> into the platform by simply placing the data inside of the folder.
>
> **Data** are CSV files that can be converted to ImpEx files

Answer (score 2):

There is a hybris Trail you can follow which explains in detail which steps need to be undertaken for a hot folder configuration:

https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094383

You can see how to define filenames, directories, time intervals and so on.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to highlight the guidelines found on your research as the link could be dead in the future